# When using .module.scss in vue3, ts error occured

Tags: typescript, vue.js, sass, vite

I have a variable in `foo.module.scss`, and I want to use that in `.vue` files.
When I import the variable into `foo.vue` , I got a ts error

```js
// foo.vue
<script lang="ts" setup>
// Module '"*.module.scss"' has no exported member 'titleColor'. Did you mean to use 'import titleColor from "*.module.scss"' instead?ts(2614)
import { titleColor } from '@/styles/var.module.scss'

// Even if I output this variable, ts will still report an error
console.log(titleColor)

</script>
```

```css
// foo.module.scss

$aside-menu-bg: pink;

:export {
  titleColor: $aside-menu-bg;
}
```

Here is a demo of my project. This error will be reported when the code is copied to the local vscode

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-yidtzb?file=src/App.vue

BTW, When I write like this, I can get what I want correctly and avoid reporting errors,but I will got a lot of things I don't want

```js
// foo.vue
<script lang="ts" setup>
import test from '@/styles/var.module.scss'

// output: a huge object
console.log(test)

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

[The Vite docs section on CSS modules](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#css-modules) explains how to enable named imports.

Alternatively, you can use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring):

```js
import scss from '@/styles/var.module.scss'
let { titleColor } from scss
```

Comment: I have configured it according to the docs in the project and forgot to write it in the demo.

Comment: Even after this configuration, if I want to use named import, it still cause ts to report an error

Comment: If I use the default import and then deconstruct it, I don't know whether it conforms to the rules of treeshaking